# What does this code do? (A question about rvalue references)

Tags: c++, reference

So I was reading "The C++ Programming Language" and this code got shown. How does it exactly work? I tried asking elsewhere, watching a video on references and another one on basic move semantics but I'm still insanely confused.

```cpp
template<typename T>
void swap(T& a, T& b)
{
  T tmp {static_cast<T&&>(a)};
  a = static_cast<T&&>(b);
  b = static_cast<T&&>(tmp);
}
```

Comment: This `static_cast<T&&>(x)` is more commonly spelled as `std::move(x)`. Googling it should give you better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is used in order to employ move semantics, if possible, with these objects. If move semantics are not possible then this automatically devolves to plain, garden-variety, copy-based swapping. The capsule summary is as follows. If you look at plain, garden-variety swapping:

```
T tmp{a};

a=b;

b=t;
```

If these objects are "heavy" there's going to be a lot of copying going on. When you say `a=b` in C++, you are making ***a complete duplicate of an object***. If `b` is a vector with a million values, congratulations: you now have two vectors with a million values. And, as soon as you have them, one of them gets destroyed (in the process of swapping). A lot of work, all for nothing.

Move semantics avoid this needless overhead in situations that boil down to moving stuff around, in the end. Instead of creating a copy of an object it is "moved" directly from point A to point B, of sorts.

Comment: Thank you. If I were to write `swap(myint, mysecondint)`, would it copy or move the values?

Comment: With `int` values there is no difference at all, whatsoever. The compiler will generate identical code. Copy/move with elementary objects is the same thing. Now, let's talk about that vector with a million values. Now you're in a completely different ballpark. If all you've got is 3gb of RAM, and a vector that takes up 2gb of it, good luck with that. A move? That'll take a few milliseconds, to move a few internal pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to `T&&` means movable reference. You could have the same effect via `std::move()`. Movable reference means the functions can have a different overload for this type. The required guarantee is that, after processing, the object that we 'move from' will remain in a valid-but-unspecified state. Sometimes it's way more effective than copying. E.g., for vectors, you might simply swap the buffers in a swap operation. The underlying operation here is `T::operator=(T&&)` that gets called.